# Callout for custom MKAnnotationView not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dictionary

I have researched this problem, unfortunately I have not gotten any solutions specific to the problem.

The problem is thus:

I have a custom MKAnnotationView with drawRect overridden. I cannot use the image property because I have this property called dotColor that impacts what the annotation view draws.

Code:

```
class CustomAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    var dotColor: UIColor!

    init(annotation: CustomAnnotation, color: UIColor) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "CustomAnnotationView")

        self.annotation = annotation
        frame.size = CGSize(width: 20, height: 20)
        dotColor = color
        opaque = false
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if annotation != nil && dotColor != nil {
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

            let circleFrame = CGRectInset(rect, 2, 2)//Needs the inset to show the stroke completely

            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor)
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, dotColor.CGColor)
            CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3)

            CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circleFrame)
            CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, circleFrame)
        }
    }

}
```

But when I click the annotation view on the map, it doesn't show the callout (I am pretty sure the MKAnnotation has a title. You could check out this thread's answer: ["If the title is nil, the callout..."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9830137/2631081))

Comment: If you could point out some mistakes made in code, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is `canShowCallout` set to `true`?  After `opaque = false`, try doing `canShowCallout = true`.

Answer (score -1):

The first thing is `colorDot = color`  so, if you want make you callout show in mapview's  `viewForAnnotation`  function.

following is example code, you can check:

`v = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "here put your identifier")
 v!.canShowCallout = true`

I doesn't understand what you want to  change exactly?  The callout background color or text or something else?

The correct way to change element in callout  is `addSubview` (either creating UIView programatically or using xib)

If you have many inaccessible things in callout, the best way to add something is not with frame. Try add layer first or `UIImage` with your stuff